# Vue.js: _this is not defined at eval -- Java Spring backend json request

Tags: java, json, spring, vue.js, get-request

Vue.js:

```
created() {
        axios.get('/people')
            .then((response) => {
                this.people = response._embedded.data.people
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    },
```

GET request response according to chrome network: https://pastebin.com/bDmKQFgB

Console log:

```
error
App.vue?234e:298 ReferenceError: _this is not defined
at eval (App.vue?234e:294)
```

The second line comes from the catch() part.

Where the json comes from: Java Spring Backend with mongodb like: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `response.data._embedded.data.people`?

Comment: @DelenaMalan yes. Additionally I also get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at eval (App.vue?234e:295)`

Comment: What does `response.data` look like, if you do: `console.log(response.data)` inside the `.then((response) => { ... })` block?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is under a different context within the `Axios` promise. Try tying `this` to a variable outside of the `Axios` promise:

Codepen mirror: https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/EJWdLr

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    title: ""
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      this.title = "Loading...";
      
      /* ============================ */
      /* THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO ADD */
      /* ============================ */
      var vm = this;
      /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
      /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
      
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then(function(response) {
          /* IN USE: */
          vm.title = response.data.title;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          alert(error);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="getData">Click to load data from api</button>
  <p>{{ title }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using arrow functions still or did you try with `.then(function(response){ ...})` ...